# htaccess mod_rewrite to omit directory name in address bar without redirecting

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, directory

I would like to use mod_rewrite in htaccess to omit a folder name in the address bar in the browser, but it's still generating the content from that location in the browser, so there's no redirect.

For example, I would like to omit all URLS with the folder name "_deploy" to omit that from the address bar.

So this:

http://www.myURL.com/_deploy/whatever.php#/whatever/whatever

Changes to this:

http://www.myURL.com/whatever.php#/whatever/whatever

It's still loading http://www.myURL.com/_deploy/whatever.php#/whatever/whatever, but what displays in the address bar is http://www.myURL.com/whatever.php#/whatever/whatever. The user can also navigate to http://www.myURL.com/whatever.php#/whatever/whatever, and that displays in the address bar, but it's really loading http://www.myURL.com/_deploy/whatever.php#/whatever/whatever.  Is this possible?

Comment: URL part after `#` is not even set to server so web server obviously cannot use in rewriting.

Comment: anubhava are you saying that the URL part after # is dynamic, and I wouldn't be able to use in rewriting? I wasn't aware that would be a limitation because rewriting URLS with parameters work.

Comment: Part after `#` is only for browsers to interpret. When request is sent to web server it is just `http://www.myURL.com/_deploy/whatever.php` omitting `#/whatever/whatever`

Comment: Scripts tack that on afterward anyway, so it doesn't really matter right? It depends on having the stuff after the #, but you still primarily navigate to _deploy/whatever.php, then the address changes after the page loads adding the stuff after the #. Is this possible if the stuff after and including the # didn't exist?

Comment: Anyway, I believe you. I guess it's impossible. Someone else said I can use Javascript.